# Need to create a view that utilizes multiple temporary tables

Tags: sql, stored-procedures, view, temp-tables

I'm trying to create a `view` from code that utilizes multiple temporary tables. I am ultimately able to completed this when my temp tables take the form of approach A:

## Approach A:

```
create view viewtest as
with temp1 as (select * from x where y),

temp2 as (select * from temp1 where z),

select * from temp2;
```

The above works, however it takes way too long to run.  I receive results much quicker when running the code below.

## Approach B:

```
select * INTO temp1 from (select * from x where y) x

select * INTO temp2 from (select * from temp1 where z)

select * from temp2;
```

However, `view` does not support this second type of temporary table.

I have created a stored procedure from Approach B, but, again, that does me no good when attempting to populate a VIEW (which is the ultimate goal) with the SP because it utilizes that type of temporary table.

My end goal is to have a view that returns quickly and efficiently - so far I've only been able to pick up speed by creating the `select * INTO` temp tables.

Comment: read this to learn [how to use code block](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help)

Comment: **Why** is creating a view your ultimate goal? A view should not be a goal, it's just a tool you can use in SQL. I suspect this is an [XYPropblem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).